# Servlet fails to work when deployed to Tomcat though it works in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, jersey, jax-rs

Two simple `POST` and `GET` URLs, *localhost:8080/mdht-restlet*, both work perfectly when run from IntelliJ IDEA. Separately, *mdht-restlet.war* dropped into */opt/tomcat/webapp* deploys, shows up in Tomcat Application Manager as running, no errors or warnings in *catalina.out*. GET and POST both produce 404. Whether I produce the WAR file from the command line, `mvn package`, or from IDEA, `Build-> Build Artifacts...`, the result is the same.

As noted, it works perfectly from IDEA Run/Debug. I'm uncertain as to what to look at. Here are some relevant details:

*web.xml* contents:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mdht-restlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.windofkeltia.servlet</param-value>
    </init-param>    
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mdht-restlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

*pom.xml* build plug-in for WAR:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the project parent directory -->
          <directory>web</directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

*MdhtRestlet.java*:

```
package com.windofkeltia.servlet;
...
@Path( "/mdht-restlet" )
public class MdhtRestlet
{
  @POST
  @Consumes( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
  @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_XML )
  public Response postPatientData( @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpHeaders header )
  {
    ...
  }

  @GET
  @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
  public String getStatusInPlainText()
  {
    return "The MDHT restlet is up.";
  }
}
```

Comment: I was quickly zeroing in on Tomcat configuration as the real problem because the rest is so simple. It turns out that if I rename mdht-restlet.war to ROOT.war and drop it into webapps, it deploys and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that Tomcat considers the name of the WAR file, in this case, *mdht-restlet.war*, to be the root (unless you rename the WAR file to *ROOT.war* which Tomcat deploys to *ROOT*), so the URL is to start with *http://localhost:8080/mdht-restlet*. Adding to that, the servlet Java code uses the `@PATH` annotation at the class level to add to the URL. That augments it to *http://localhost:8080/mdht-restlet/mdht-restlet*, so the shorter URL was never going to do otherwise than 404.

Why did this get by IntelliJ IDEA? Probably because of how the `Run/Debug Configuration` was set up between the settings in the `Server` tab (for Tomcat) and the `Deployment` tab. These did not follow (the points made in my first paragraph) and so gave a false impression of success (because they were jacked).